# VBA Define Variable names from members of an array

Tags: arrays, vba

Good morning,

I am using VBA and my problem in brief is that i would like to have a bit of code that will set up a new variable with the name of every member of an array.

Background:
The initial array that is being created by reading an XML file taking the information in all the child noes as the value of each member of the array. So for example. If i had some XML such as:

```
<dimensions>
   <dimension>
      dim1
   </dimension>
   <dimension>
      dim2
   </dimension>
   <dimension>
      dim3
   </dimension>
</dimensions>
```

My code so far generates and array, lets call it my_array() with 3 members:

```
my_array(0)=dim1
my_array(1)=dim2
my_array(2)=dim3
```

My Issue:
What i would then like to be able to do is to loop through all the members of my_array()and produce new variables named after each member. So as a result in  this simple case end up with 3 new variables defined dim1, dim2, dim3.

My attempt so far:

```
dim i as integer
for i=0 to Ubound(my_array)
   dim my_array(i) as string
next i
```

I was hoping this would define a new variable each time the loop runs. As the number of members of my_array depends on the file being read I don't know how many variables will need to be defined or I could just predefined them for use later.

Is what i want possible, am I thinking of this in the correct way?

The next step is that instead of defining simple variables each loop would create a new dictionary for use later, but that's an upgrade for a later date.

Many thanks

Comment: If you were able to define variables in this way, how would you code using them later, given that you don't know their names in advance?

Comment: I will be running the same analysis on each variable created so as i know the list of dimensions is contained within my_array(). I can loop through my list of dimensions passing each member of my_array() to various functions to return results.

Comment: The standard approach for things along these lines is to create a dictionary. A dictionary essentially *is* a collection of names which can be defined and used as variables during run time. You seem to be aware of this but refer to it as an "upgrade for a later date". Why wait?

Comment: Yes exactly, in reality the XML doc is much more complicated than the above example with each dimension having children of its own. The plan is create my_array() as list of all the dimensions. Then creating dictionaries for each dimension that will contain the child nodes of that dimension as keys and a string of each child's attributes against each key. Resulting in 1 dictionary for each dimension in my_array with information about it's child nodes stored within. Which is lovely but still begs the questions can i define something by lopping through my array and naming the variable accordingly

Comment: You can write VBA code which will generate another VBA code, have a look e.g. [here](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbe.aspx). So you can e.g. add new standard module and write all the declarations for all the variables in it.

Comment: You can create a dictionary of dictionaries. You only need 1 top-level name defined at code time, everything else can be created dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to script the VBA editor (which is a lot of work compared to using dictionaries) but you still want to automatically generate a lot of Dim statements for later use, you could write a sub which generates the dim statements as strings and then prints them to the Immediate Window:

```
Sub test()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim my_array As Variant
    Dim dims As String
    
    my_array = Array("dim1", "dim2", "dim3")
    
    For i = 0 To UBound(my_array)
        dims = dims & "Dim " & my_array(i) & " As String" & vbCrLf
    Next i
    Debug.Print dims
End Sub
```

Output looks like:

[image]

You would still need to manually copy/paste into the editor, but this might save a bit of typing. Obviously this isn't a very robust solution, but every now and then I have found it useful to generate repetitive code by writing a helper sub that creates the code as a string and prints it to the immediate window.

Comment: Thanks John, that is a handy little trick. It looks as though I'm going to have to come up with different solution for storing all the information.